# Action Bar colors are bugged

Tags: java, android, xml

I've started my project with a "Navigation Drawer Activity" in Android Studio 2.2.3. Then changed the parent of AppTheme to Theme.AppCompat.Light and the primary and secondary color to a white color. However, when I open my main activity I noticed that the hamburger icon and the overflow menu icon are slightly lighter than the pitch black title in the appbar, see left screenshot. However, what's weird is that when I go to a second blank activity the up arrow and any other icon I place in the navigation bar are as black as the title. Does anyone know where this styling is coming from so I can change it? My code is shown below the screenshot.

My main goal is to change the color of the hamburger and overflow menu icon.

[image: Main activity and activity after FAB click]

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a fix. Editing the color of the hamburger icon can be done by adding

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    (...)
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/materialBlackPrimary</item>
</style>
```

and editing the color of the overflow menu icon can be done by adding

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    (...)
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="OverflowButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:tint">@color/materialBlackPrimary</item>
</style>
```